Graph API subscription change notification response timeout
I have a Graph API subscription/webhook setup for Teams Call data. The subscription itself is fine and I have been keeping it updated for months. The issue is with the change notification response. According to Microsoft we need to response with a 2xx code to each change notification to acknowledge receipt. Microsoft official instructions can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/change-notifications-delivery-webhooks?tabs=http
It says that if you can response with 3 seconds, then send a 200, or if it's going to take longer than 10 seconds, send a 202 to queue the notification. I tried setting up the 200 at first, but I noticed that some of the responses were getting timed out, even some that were sub 3 seconds. So I switched it to 202, but I still see the same issue, and almost nothing is taking longer than 10 seconds, very rarely. And some are sub 3 seconds. What I don't understand is when to use the 202 code. Are we supposed to send the 202 code BEFORE we start processing to let Graph know that we will need more than 10 seconds? And the according to the documentation it seems like we have up to 10 seconds to respond, but nearly all my timeout failures are sub 10 seconds. If anyone has any insight on how this is supposed to work I would appreciate it. I can't seem to find anything concreate on this subject online.
To be clear, most of my responses are working fine. But a handful of them are getting the timeout. And this is making it look like I have errors in the flow and it's going to be difficult to quickly distinguish if these errors are all related to the response, or if something else went wrong that might impact production.
Also, I am aware that Graph API will resend those notifications if they don't get back the the response, and that is not an issue as I keep track of the items I have processed and don't reprocess them if they are sent to me again.
